# Where's my error with this springs and masses in series problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, physics

Say I have a mass $m_1$ attached to a spring $s_1$, the other end of which is fixed. Then, I have another mass $m_2$ attached to a spring $s_2$, the other end of which is attached to $m_1$. Gravity applies to the masses.

(ceiling) - $s_1$ - $m_1$ - $s_2$ - $m_2$

The spring constants for $s_1$ and $s_2$ are $k_1$ and $k_2$, respectively.

I need someone to look over my equilibrium equations because I've done so a few times and they look correct, but my solution doesn't look correct.

$$
\begin{aligned}
m_1y_1'' - k_1y_1 - k_2y_1 + k_2y_2 &= 0\\
m_2y_2'' - k_2y_2 + k_2y_1 &= 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearrange a little:

$$
\begin{aligned}
m_1y_1'' - (k_1 + k_2)y_1 + k_2y_2 &= 0\\
m_2y_2'' + k_2y_1 - k_2y_2 &= 0\\\\
m_1y_1'' &= (k_1 + k_2)y_1 - k_2y_2\\
m_2y_2'' &= - k_2y_1 + k_2y_2\\\\
y_1'' &= \frac{k_1 + k_2}{m_1}y_1 - \frac{k_2}{m_1}y_2\\
y_2'' &= \frac{-k_2}{m_2}y_1 + \frac{k_2}{m_2}y_2\\
\end{aligned}
$$

The constant values are $k_1=3$, $k_2=2$, $m_1=1$, $m_2=1$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1'' &= 5y_1 - 2y_2\\
y_2'' &= -2y_1 + 2y_2\\
\end{aligned}
$$

In matrix form I have:

$$
\bar y'' = \bar A \bar y, \bar A=\begin{bmatrix}5 & -2\\\ -2 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I assume a solution $y$ has the form $\bar y = \bar v e^{\omega t}$, then

$$
\omega^2 \bar v e^{\omega t} = \bar A \bar v e^{\omega t}\\
\omega^2 \bar v  = \bar A \bar v
$$

Sub. $\omega^2 = \lambda$ gives me
$$
\lambda \bar v  = \bar A \bar v
$$

From this point, I'm solving for eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the usual way. I get

$$
\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = 6.
$$

With $\lambda_1$, I get $\bar v = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$. With $\lambda_2$, I get $\bar v = \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

So I get the solution

$$
\bar y = c_1 \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\\ 1\end{bmatrix}e^{\sqrt 6 t} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 2\end{bmatrix}e^{\sqrt t}
$$

Since the square roots really give me two solutions each, I can manipulate this into

$$
\bar y = c_1 \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\\ 1\end{bmatrix}cosh(\sqrt 6 t) + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 2\end{bmatrix} cosh(t)
$$

I can't find an error, but the solution doesn't make sense to me; I'd expect the system to oscillate and the solution doesn't.

What's my mistake?

Comment: Suppose you get rid the second spring by setting $k_2=0$. (Physically, you’re eliminating the restoring force due to the second spring.) Then your first ODE becomes $my_1’’=k_1 y_1$, which has the wrong signs for harmonic motion. So you’ll need to re-examine your equations of motion.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks, I think that's it. I was just looking at my plots and it looks like they behave correctly if time were going backwards, so I suspected there's a sign wrong.

Comment: As a sanity check: If $y_1$ increases, then the (negative) force of the first spring on mass 1 increases and the (positive) force of the second spring on mass 1 decreases. So the contribution of $y_1$ to the net force on mass 1 should be $-k_1(y_1)+k_2(-y_1)=-(k_1+k_2)y_1$, i.e., both are restoring forces.